# Da dove ha origine il modo di dire "sparare sulla Croce Rossa"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Leggevo la [pagina Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerra_d%27Etiopia#La_marcia_su_Neghelli) sulla guerra d'Etiopia e mi sono imbattuta in un episodio in cui un generale bombarda un accampamento etiope situato vicino a un ospedale della Croce Rossa svedese, colpendolo e suscitando reazioni indignate dell'opinione pubblica internazionale.

Quest'episodio mi ha fatto venire in mente il modo di dire "sparare sulla Croce Rossa". Quando è stato usato per la prima volta? È possibile che quest'episodio del colonialismo italiano ne sia l'origine?

Quel che è sicuro è che la prima attestazione non può precedere il 1863, data di fondazione della Croce Rossa...

Answer (score 4):

Sembra non ci sia un’origine certa ma si tratti di una metafora che si è naturalmente diffusa nel linguaggio comune. Interessante  come l’uso si sia esteso per indicare fatti ovvi o scontati. Da notare che ci sono stati vari episodi in cui i mezzi della [Croce Rossa](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sparare%20sulla%20croce%20rossa%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1960&lr=lang_it) venivano presi di mira durante i conflitti, per cui la metafora ha comunque un’origine da fatti realmente accaduti:

Da *La scuola positiva nella dottrina e nella giurisprudenza penale.*

> 1916 - ‎... convenzionale dell'Aia, indugiandosi a rilevare i divieti di uccidere i prigionieri, di far impiego di sicarii, di usar l'uniforme militare del nemico, dello sparare sulla Croce Rossa, di adoperar la bandiera bianca per valersene come tranello.

La Croce  Rossa:

> ***Non è possibile stabilire con certezza quando sia nato il modo di dire sparare sulla croce rossa, ma certo con questa espressione si faceva riferimento a un atto vile rivolto contro chi, inerme, andava in soccorso di chi stava male***.
>
> La lingua ha tuttavia la capacità di trasformare modi di dire originariamente seri e severi in motti leggeri e scherzosi: oggi sparare sulla croce rossa? viene usato anche per indicare una facile sopraffazione o addirittura una vittoria scontata.> fondata a Ginevra nell’agosto del 1864, ebbe come scopo originario
> quello di soccorrere i feriti in guerra. Poi la sua finalità si è
> estesa a prestare assistenza ai feriti in occasione di calamità
> naturali e via via ai feriti in generale, con il nascere dei comitati
> nei diversi Stati.

([Corriere.it](http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/08-07-2008/sparare_sulla_croce_rossa-1092085.html))

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sparare%20sulla%20Croce%20Rossa&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csparare%20sulla%20Croce%20Rossa%3B%2Cc0) mostra l’uso di questo modo di dire dall’inizio degli anni ‘60, ma molto probabilmente era già in uso prima.

Da “Ferito a morte”: romanzo - Pagina 193
Raffaele La Capria - 1961 - ‎

> Spara, spara! Continua a sparare sulla Croce Rossa! Ma tu pure, però... " " Come stai? " " A te lo posso dire, la sai la storia dello scarafone? — Piove inchiostro. E quello: Che me ne importa, tanto mai più nero di come sono posso diventare.

Comment: Potresti aggiungere i link?

Answer (score -1):

Credo di conoscere l'origine: prima che nascessero i videogiochi sparatutto c'era uno sparatutto interamente elettromeccanico dove, in un percorso di guerra, scorrevano carri armati jeep e altro a velocità diverse e proporzionate ai punteggi, ogni tanto e mooolto lenta, passava una ambulanza con la croce rossa che era impossibile mancare e valeva un solo punto. Evidente che sparare sulla croce rossa era l'unica cosa  che riusciva anche ai più scarsi: ed ecco l'origine di un detto che oggi ha sostituito quello che, a quei tempi, si sarebbe detto con un altro modo di dire ora desueto: "sparare a un uomo morto".

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: A questa risposta farebbe bene qualche fonte, se ne esistono.

Comment: Scusa, @Marco, ma di che anni è il gioco di cui stai parlando?